# How to make two Ionic-side-menus on the same page? IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, menu, ionic3

I am making a ionic project and i want to have one left menu and one right menu,and the content on the midle.

My poblem is that i can only place one ionic-menu. I tried to place both, but only one appears.

The problems i get i where i place my , because both menus on the ionic docs have one.

This is my code:

Menu: 1 :

```
<ion-split-pane contentId="main" >
  <!--  the side menu  -->
  <ion-menu side="start" menu-id="test1">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
  </ion-menu>

  <!-- the main content -->
  <ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-split-pane>
```

Menu 2:

```
<ion-split-pane contentId="main" >
  <!--  the side menu  -->
  <ion-menu side="start" menu-id="test1">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
  </ion-menu>

  <!-- the main content -->
  <ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-split-pane>
```

Main content:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Receitas</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-menu-button slot="start">TEste</ion-menu-button>
    <ion-menu-button slot="end">TEste</ion-menu-button>
</ion-content>
```

These are in separated files.

I want this :

[image: What i want]

But when i run the page, only one menu is displayed, the start one.

Comment: Is it the real code you use on your app ? Because in your two menu you specify `side="start"`

Comment: not its not, i copied the menu 1, but forgot to change to end

Answer (score 5):

You need to add another ion-menu to you app.component.html and ensure you add the “side” attribute:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    <ion-menu side="start" contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list id="inbox-list">
          <ion-list-header>Inbox</ion-list-header>
          <ion-note>hi@ionicframework.com</ion-note>

          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">
            <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" routerDirection="root" [routerLink]="[p.url]" lines="none" detail="false" [class.selected]="selectedIndex == i">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list id="labels-list">
          <ion-list-header>Labels</ion-list-header>

          <ion-item *ngFor="let label of labels" lines="none">
            <ion-icon slot="start" ios="bookmark-outline" md="bookmark-sharp"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>{{ label }}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>

    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
    
    <ion-menu side="end" contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list id="inbox-list">
          <ion-list-header>Inbox</ion-list-header>
          <ion-note>hi@ionicframework.com</ion-note>

          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">
            <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" routerDirection="root" [routerLink]="[p.url]" lines="none" detail="false" [class.selected]="selectedIndex == i">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list id="labels-list">
          <ion-list-header>Labels</ion-list-header>

          <ion-item *ngFor="let label of labels" lines="none">
            <ion-icon slot="start" ios="bookmark-outline" md="bookmark-sharp"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>{{ label }}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Now in order to feature menu buttons in each of the pages you need to add another ion-menu-button and use "menu" attribute to indicate which side it controls:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button menu="start"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{ folder }}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-menu-button menu="end"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Above I used standard sidemenu ionic app (ionic start, then choose sidemenu app template)

Comment: Thanks! Can u explain what the things you add do?

Comment: Hey Fabio, basically first you add another menu to exist and second you add a way to feature a menu button to a page that will control open/close state of it. Do you feel like it’s not clear from the answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use my code. I think it is the right answer

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu side="start" menuId="start" contentId="main">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="tertiary">
        <ion-title>Menu Left</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding"></ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-menu side="end" menuId="end" contentId="main">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="tertiary">
        <ion-title>Menu right</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding"></ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <div id="main">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-button menu="start" color="light">
            <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
          </ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
          <ion-menu-button menu="end" color="light">
            <ion-icon name="ellipsis-vertical-sharp"></ion-icon>
          </ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">
    </ion-content>
  </div>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).